# List<object> to List<SomeObject> dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I have a object:

```
List<Object> res= SomeList of Objects
```

I want to Cast res to another object let say "company". The simplest way to do this is:

```
res.cast<company>().ToList();
```

But I want to do it dynamically. I want to pass Company in form of an object. is there any way to do this?
Company is an Entity object.
Thanks-- AG

Comment: Why not use `List<company>`?

Comment: Are you trying to cast to a `List<company>`?

Comment: You are probably looking for either Dynamic Linq or AutoMapper. Google 'em

Comment: if you're using EF seems like you'd want to use generic types, not objects

Comment: Hi, I don't know why it is marked as unclear. I clearly stated that I want to pass an Entity type in Cast<TResult>. We usually do that like object.cast<company>. Question is how we can make it dynamic ? So that we need not specify cast<company> at runtime rather we can create a reference to  it and use that. In this way we can Dynamically cast any List<object> to a referenced object.

Comment: Regarding Dynamic Linq, we need to specify the Object explicitly we can create any Dynamic Query on an Specified Object, Same true for DTO objects in Auto Mapper I Suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is generic type casting i think you could use a generic function for this something like this

```
public static List<T> MyCastingFunction<T>(List<object> res)
{
return res.cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

and you can call it as

```
List<Company> companyList= MyCastingFunction<company>(res);
```

or if you want to cast it to some other type then

```
List<AnyOtherType> otherList=MyCastingFunction<AnyOtherType>(res);
```